# PHP Formstack->Wordpress Webhook

Tags: php, wordpress, formstack

I have a problem that I am not sure how to fix.

I have a formstack form on my wordpress site. It allows people to buy a product. For this
particular page, there is only one item available for sale, so once the
form is processed (data sent to Formstack->Stripe and payment confirmation received),
the page needs to "turn off" so others can't purchase the item.

Before I used formstack, I used gravity forms plugin.

When the form submitted, I had a add_action filter in my functions.php in
wordpress. It fired when gravity forms completed the submission process and
ran a function that turned off the page.

Here is that code that worked beautifully.

```
add_action("gform_after_submission", "set_post_content", 10, 2);
function set_post_content(){

global $cfs;

$field_data = array('sold' => '1');
$post_data = array('ID' => get_the_ID()); // the ID is required
$cfs->save($field_data, $post_data);
}
```

I see formstack has a webhook function.

I cannot seem to find code on how to parse the data the formstack webhook sends. I used http://requestb.in/ to see the data that was being sent.

I believe I need to use php://input, but once I read the data, I am not sure how to say

If formstack webhook fires, then run this code

```
    function set_post_content(){

    global $cfs;

    $field_data = array('sold' => '1');
    $post_data = array('ID' => get_the_ID()); // the ID is required
    $cfs->save($field_data, $post_data);
    }
```

I also believe the code needs to be in the functions.php in my theme file because otherwise it won't understand the $cfs variable that is from another wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this new formstack function the other day - it sounds like it could solve your problem?http://support.formstack.com/customer/portal/articles/1444519-event-fields

Event handling options

When your Event has filled to capacity, you can mark the Event as "Sold Out" so new submitters will see the item is no longer available.  You may also choose to hide this field on the Form once the items have sold out.  Additionally, you can deactivate the whole Form when the Event has sold out; this is done through the Form Settings tab > General > Deactivate Form settings.